# Exception Progress Bar Maximum y minimum

Tags: c#, progressbar

Error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '31' is not valid for
>   'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter
>   name: Value'

En esta linea:

```
 if (bar.InvokeRequired)
     {
      //linea donde da el error
      bar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { bar.Value++; }));
     }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de la propiedad Maximum?

Answer (score 0):

Las barras de progreso tienen tres propiedades: el valor mínimo, el valor máximo y el valor actual. El valor actual nunca puede estar fuera del intervalo mínimo / máximo.

Prueba con ésto

```
 if (bar.InvokeRequired)
     {
      bar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { if (bar.Value < bar.Maximum - 1) bar.Value++; }));
     }
```